# To check whether current date is not less than present date in dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on JavaScript validation where I am validating whether a `textbox` date is equal to the current date or not.

If its greater or equal to today's date than do something, if its less than today's date then show error message.

Note: In my `textbox` I have converted date into `dd/MM/yyyy` format. So I need to check `textbox` date with current date in `dd/MM/yyy` format only. Here is my code:

```
function ValidateDate() {
var EffectiveDate = $.trim($("[id$='txtFromDate']").val());
var Today = new Date();
if(EffectiveDate<Today())
{
     //Show Error Message
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

I need the date to be in `dd/MM/yyyy` format for checking my `textbox` date, so my `Today` value has to be in `dd/MM/yyyy` format only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to find the current date -- below is code that finds it. Then, compare the result with the value entered in TextBox.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
} 

if(mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
} 

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
document.write(today);

var EffectiveDate = $.trim($("[id$='txtFromDate']").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ValidateAddNewCourseCharge() {
var EffectiveDate = $.trim($("[id$='txtFromDate']").val());
var Today = new Date();
var dd = Today.getDate();
var mm = Today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = Today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}
var Today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

dateFirst = EffectiveDate.split('/');
dateSecond = Today.split('/');
var value = new Date(dateFirst[2], dateFirst[1], dateFirst[0]);
var current = new Date(dateSecond[2], dateSecond[1], dateSecond[0]);

if (EffectiveDate == "") {
    showErrorMessagePopUp("Please Select a Date for Course Charge!");
    return false;
}
else {
    if (value < current) {
        showErrorMessagePopUp("Date should not be less than Present Date!");
        return false;
    }
}    
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help for you

```
var getdate = new Date($("[id$='txtFromDate']").val());
var curDate = new Date();

alert(getdate - curDate === 0);
alert(getdate - curDate < 0);
alert(getdate - curDate > 0);
```